# Cannot talk to another container inside same task on ECS Fargate using awsvpc networking type

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc, aws-fargate

I am running a standard SPA frontend app and a node server in the same ECS task.

Everything that I have read about `awsvpc` can use `localhost` when 2 containers inside the same task are interfacing with each other.

However, with this set up I can't seem to return data from my node server to my UI. All my requests immediately fail. I have asserted that it is actually trying to hit `localhost` on my actual computer.

**Browser failure:**
https://pasteboard.co/JFJLnLO.png

For testing purposes I exposed port `8080` to see if I could interact with the node server directly and that works as expected. I just cant get the UI to talk to it.

Any help would be much appreciated

EDIT:

My task definition looks like this:

```
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "essential": true,
      "image": "[my-account-id].dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/[my-account]/app-ui:latest",
      "name": "app-ui",
      "logConfiguration": {
        "logDriver": "awslogs",
        "options": {
          "awslogs-group": "/ecs/app-ui",
          "awslogs-region": "eu-west-1",
          "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs",
          "awslogs-create-group": "true"
        }
      },
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "containerPort": 3000,
          "hostPort": 3000,
          "protocol": "tcp"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "essential": true,
      "image": "[my-account-id].dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/[my-account]/app-api:latest",
      "name": "app-api",
      "logConfiguration": {
        "logDriver": "awslogs",
        "options": {
          "awslogs-group": "/ecs/app-api",
          "awslogs-region": "eu-west-1",
          "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs",
          "awslogs-create-group": "true"
        }
      },
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "containerPort": 8080,
          "hostPort": 8080,
          "protocol": "tcp"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "cpu": "256",
  "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::[my-account-id]:role/AWSServiceRoleECS",
  "family": "app",
  "memory": "512",
  "networkMode": "awsvpc",
  "requiresCompatibilities": ["FARGATE"]
}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7zl3.png
```

Comment: What does your task definition look like?

Comment: @dpwrussell I have added my task-definition to the post ^^

Comment: Can you clarify how do you call the api on port 8080? You have screenshot showing browser calling localhost:8080? So you are running the browser inside of your container somehow?

Comment: @Marcin I posted browser failure image

Comment: Running chrome directly on my own machine

Comment: But localhost will resolve to your own machine, not to your task. So I'm not really sure how your application is supposed to work?

Comment: @Marcin So I am going by the docs over here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-networking.html

It says

`containers that belong to the same task can communicate over the localhost interface.`

Comment: @Marcin I also understand what you are saying. I just don't know how else to interpret that statement in the docs.

Comment: Yes, that's how it works. But this is within the task. You can't call localhost from your browser over the internet. For that you need regular, public dns for the API. Localhost would work if your browser was running in the container wiithin the task, not outside the task.

Comment: Ah I see. I am being totally dumb, sorry. I gotta package up the public dns as an env var to the UI. I understand what you are saying. It's been a long night :')

Comment: No problem. If you don't mind I will provide an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue is caused by calling `localhost` api endpoint in on the **client side** in the browser. This will resolve to `localhost` on the client machine, not within the ECS tasks. The `localhost` will work when the API is called from the inside of the ECS task, not from outside of the task.

To call the API endpoint from the client side, regular public IP or public DNS is required, not `localhost`.

Comment: I would be very grateful if you looked at my other question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65384116/how-can-i-make-a-request-to-my-api-from-my-ui-when-they-are-both-containers-runn