# How can I make a request to my API from my UI when they are both containers running in the same task in ECS Fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-fargate, amazon-elb

I have set up a a cluster, with 1 service containing 1 task. The task contains 2 docker containers. One for my UI (post `3000`) and one for my API (port `8080`). I can access both ports via `[public-ip]:3000` and `[public-ip]:8080`.

I then set up an `Application Load Balancer` that points to the service. It points these `target group`:

https://pasteboard.co/JFQfvD9.png

So now I `CAN` reach the `UI` via the `DNS name` for the load balancer but the API calls that the application makes always fail with `404`.

This is the browser network request to the API

https://pasteboard.co/JFQjISle.png

**Worth noting**
The target group only goes to `port 3000`. I would assume I need to target `port 8080` here as well? They are also unhealthy and keept restarting but that is a side effect of not being able to find my health check endpoint which is `8080/api/ping`.

I am not really sure where I am going wrong here.

Any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT**

**Security Group**
https://pasteboard.co/JFRBE80.png

**ALB**
https://pasteboard.co/JFRHgKU.png

**TG Health check settings**
https://pasteboard.co/JFRIkRn.png

**ALB info on ECS service**
https://pasteboard.co/JFRXYim.png

**Trying to update ECS service**
https://pasteboard.co/JFRYyjz.png

**Creating a new service, can only add 1 container to be load balanced**
https://pasteboard.co/JFS0yDW.png

Comment: Can anyone help with this?

Comment: What are security groups on your AWSVPC service?

Comment: @Marcin Uploaded security group image.

Comment: When you write " I can access both ports", you mean that the ui and api work when access directly. The only issue is with the ALB?

Comment: Yes, you will need to TGs. Also you need to provide more info about ALB setting. TG setings, health check settings?

Comment: @Marcin I uploaded ALB and TG health check settings

Comment: @Marcin "I can access both parts", I mean that I can access both directly. However, the UI calls to the API and fails. That is shown in the browser screenshot above.

Comment: @Marcin Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: Your TG uses port 80, but UI and API use different ports. You need 2 TGs, one for each port you want to use in the ECS service with correctly set ports.

Comment: @Marcin I am not sure how to do that because if I add a TG I need to know the specific IP which are ephemeral with fargate as you know :S

Comment: You set ALB through your ECS service. For existing service, you need to update it.

Comment: @Marcin I have added more screenshots. So what I am finding is that by either creating or updating a service I can only add one container to be load balanced

Comment: @Marcin I was able to get it working with what you suggested! Registering TGs on each of the ports and setting a rule in the ALB for /api/* -> 8080 and /* -> 3000. Would you like to add an answer?

Comment: Glad to hear. Yes. I will add an answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was caused by misconfiguration of ports in target group of the load balancer.

The solution was to correctly set the ports so that they match those used in the ecs service.